# Error with Coldfusion cftransaction tag

Tags: coldfusion

I'm working with ColdFusion 11 and am getting an error with cftransaction. I'm not sure what causing it.

I have two CFC's: abc.cfc and xyz.cfc. `abc.cfc` does not use the datasource attribute: as it is defined in the Application.cfc using `this.datasource`.

Here is the error:

```
Error! The root cause was that: java.sql.SQLException: Usernames and Passwords for all the database tags within the cftransaction tag must be the same. Datasource inventorymgt verification failed.. Entry rolled back
```

What I am doing is:

```
<cftransaction action="begin">
    <cftry>
            <cfscript>
                f = structNew();
                f.companyName = '#arguments.structform.companyname#';
                f.address = '#arguments.structform.address#';
                f.settingsID = arguments.structform.settingsID;                 
                r = tblUpdate('settings',f);
                sresult = 'Updated';
            </cfscript> 
      <cfset str = "Cool! Settings has been " & sresult>
      <cftransaction action="commit"/>      
      <cfcatch type="any">       
        <cftransaction action="rollback"/>
        <cfset str = "Error! #cfcatch.Detail# #cfcatch.Message#. Entry rolled back">
      </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
  </cftransaction>
```

And another CFC which is expecting the init function like the datasource, username,password is using the following query way to update it:

```
<cfquery name="q" 
      datasource="#variables.dbsource#" 
      username="#variables.dbuname#" 
      password="#variables.dbpword#">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is explained in this post:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cfwheels/AZTvxvhsapc

Within a cftransaction tag, every query has to use the same authentification. You cannot have one query use a datatasource and the other use a username and password within the same transaction.

I would agree with the author of the link. I always just define the datasource once in the cf-administrator, so I don't have to deal with username/password. Then you can initialize your cfc just by datasource.

I don't know what your function *tblUpdate* is actually doing, but might be that you use a different syntax than in the query you posted? Because, that's what your error code says:

> Usernames and Passwords for all the database tags within the cftransaction tag must be the same.